# Java client using SAAJ error: SEVERE: SAAJ0008: Bad Response; Unauthorized

Tags: java, web-services, saaj

I have written a Java client code using SAAJ for Primevera P6 webservices. I am getting the below authentication error. I am providing the http username + password to the code but it gives error: SEVERE: SAAJ0008: Bad Response; Unauthorized. Could some one please help me with this issue. I am stuck in this problem since a long time. The wsdl of the web service is: https://sunpower-p6.oracleindustry.com/p6ws-token/services/ProjectService?wsdl.

ERROR: 
Request SOAP Message = 
11106
Jul 18, 2016 1:03:19 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
SEVERE: SAAJ0008: Bad Response; Unauthorized
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (401Unauthorized

My code:

```
public class TestClient {

    /*
     Method used to create the SOAP Request
    */
    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {

        // Next, create the actual message
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage    soapMessage    = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart       soapPart       = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();


        String serverURI = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/Primavera/P6/WS/Project/V2";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ProjectService", serverURI);

        //start: setting HTTP headers - optional, comment out if not needed
        String      authorization = Base64Coder.encodeString("xyz:abc");
        MimeHeaders hd            = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);
        //end: setting HTTP headers

        // Create and populate the body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();

        // Create the main element and namespace
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem  = soapBody.addChildElement("ReadProjects", "ProjectService");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Field", "ProjectService");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem1.addChildElement("Id", "ProjectService");
        soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("11106");

        hd.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "ReadProjects");

        // Save the message
        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        // Check the input
        System.out.println("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();
        return soapMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Method used to print the SOAP Response
     */
    private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
        // Create the transformer
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer        transformer        = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

        // Extract the content of the reply
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();

        // Set the output for the transformation
        System.out.println("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            // First create the connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection        soapConnection        = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
            //System.out.println(soapConnection);

            //Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            String url = "https://sunpower-p6.oracleindustry.com/p6ws-token/services/ProjectService?wsdl";
            // Send the message and get the reply
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

            // Process the SOAP Response
            printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but would like to leave some assistance to anyone in the future who ends up here (like I did). There is a few likely situations that I have recently experienced regarding this.

1. Check that your details are correct, or that the connection is possible. Be 100% sure before moving on.
2. You will receive an unauthorized error if your database is not correctly configured for some setups (for instance, on JBoss). In my situation the data-source file was not being read properly when it attempted to connect causing the Unauthorized error on the client side.